# Android phone does not appear in lsusb after entering "downloading" mode!

Tags: usb, android

I've been trying to use Heimdall to install custom ROMs on my Samsung Galaxy GT-i8190 (Galaxy S3 Mini), but running

```
sudo heimdall detect
```

Gives

```
ERROR: Failed to detect compatible download-mode device.`
```

I just noticed that when the device is in "download" mode, it doesn't even appear in the list of connected USB devices!

Here is the output of `lsusb` when device is connected in normal mode:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 023: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Notice the phone on 003:023? Well, then I put it in download mode (running `sudo adb reboot download` or the long-press V-, Power and Home key for a few seconds). Device is still connected. USB debug mode is on. Here's the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The only line missing now is the one with the device, ergo device is effectively not connected to any USB port, thus `heimdall detect` won't be able to detect it. Are there any external drivers I need? Can anyone provide any input?

Comment: Zia, did you ever find a solution to this issue? (sorry can't comment, I only have reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't. I ended up hooking my phone to a Windows phone and downloading the custom ROM. On an unrelated note, I would not advise downloading custom ROMs on a GT-i8190. Battery will most probably give out and with CM11 I experienced charging issues. You didn't ask for this and it's not a place of this, but be careful. Get a bigger phone. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the suggestions out there on how to fix similar (but not the same issue as this) include;

- Ensure you have the udev rules setup correctly - see [installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK#Preparing_Hardware)
- Trying different USB cables
- Trying different USB ports
- Restarting the computer
- Ensure you're using USB2 ports

However, for me, none of these worked, even though it would appear that the USB port was good, that is until you switch to download mode.

I experienced this on both Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and Windows 7 on the same machine.

I thought perhaps because the issue occurred in both Linux and Windows and the USB ports seemingly worked fine when not in download mode that it must be an issue with the phone. On the phone I checked that;

- [KNOX](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/mobile/platform/mobile-platform/knox/) wasn't running
- Performed a factory reset, several times, as some users out there seem to have reported success on their third or fourth factory resets

Finally I tried on an older Dell laptop, running Ubuntu 10.04, using the cable supplied with the phone, and it worked flawlessly first time.

So, my suggestion would be that perhaps try a different computer.

<strike>I'm yet to confirm whether the issue is related to the Ubuntu version, but I'll do that later today.</strike> Confirmed, Ubuntu 14.04 works fine on another machine.

Comment: I confirm that some USB cables just have most pins missing, only few of them exists for charging.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04. It was the USB cable all along. Don't use flimsy alternatives. Use the ones you got with the device.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a mode to make it work. You can boot Ubuntu from USB, then the phone in download mode appear right on lsusb and other tools (heimdall etc.). I have the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. Tried couple of phones in download mode and they are wrongly recognized. Somewhere in the system it has remembered the first phone. Changing USB Cable doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Rugby I547 on LinuxMint 17 32-bit here..

For me the solution was to POWER OFF the phone and Power On again.

It was working fine, then when I unplugged the USB cable and plugged it back in, the phone did not appear in lsusb.

Restarting the phone did not solve it.

Powering off the phone and powering on again did.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by rebooting the Pixel 3XL.