# Android device not recognized by specific computer

Tags: usb, android, udev

I have a peculiar issue with my phone - it is not recognized by ONLY my home computer. Phone is a OnePlus 3 (05c6:676c). Computer is running Kubuntu 16.04 with the 4.14.0-041400-generic kernel. Udev rules installed from the android-tools-usb package.

Symptoms:

- does not appear in lsusb output
- nothing in `dmesg`
- nothing in syslog
- device does charge

What I've tried:

- restarting
- different USB cables (different brand, stock from package, etc) - doesn't help
- different USB3 port - doesn't help
- different USB2 port - doesn't help
- my phone using same USB cable on different computer (same OS and kernel) - works fine
- different phone on any combination of above - works fine

What I've checked:

- udev rules - nothing references the device specifically
- module blacklist - didn't think this would help since other phones work fine, but regardless, didn't see anything there

Does anybody have any suggestions for what I can try to diagnose this issue? I'm out of ideas to try at this point. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: it would seem at least one other person has had a very similar issue but seems like their solution was to just switch computers but that is not an option for me right now: https://askubuntu.com/a/568892

Comment: Try disable USB3 if possible from the BIOS.